# How can I share model methods between the client and the server in loopback?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, isomorphic-javascript

I want to share some business logic both on the client and the server.

Let's say it is a file API, and I want to know if an item has a type of folder.

On the server it looks like this:

```
Content.prototype.isFolder = function() {
    return this.type === 'folder';
}
```

Is it currently possible to expose this in an easy manner to the client?

We are also using loopback-sdk-angular. Integrating with that is the ultimate goal.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

You can create a shared library that has the isFolder method, and use this both on the server, and the browserified version on the client.

How you easily integrate that with angular is another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new [remote method](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extend+your+API), to expose it to the REST API:

```
Model.remoteMethod(
    'isFolder',
    {
        http: { path: '/isFolder', verb: 'get' },
        accepts: [
            {
                arg: 'id',
                type: 'string',
                required: true,
                http: {
                    source: 'query'
                }
            },
        ],
        returns: { arg: 'isFolder', type: 'boolean' }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! It does however not answer the question how to share the business logic that not necessarily need to be a remote method. In some cases like in this example it would not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `common` directory at the project root. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/common+directory